# A general question about Isomorphism Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to ask a general question about $p^2$-groups. How can I know if a group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ or to $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$ ?

Thanks

Comment: If it is cyclic then it is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{p^2},$ and if it is not, then it is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_p \times \mathbb Z_p.$

Answer (score 1):

$G\simeq\Bbb Z_{p^2}$ iff $G$ is cyclic, i.e. iff $\exists g\in G\;$ s.t. $G=\langle g\rangle$.

If such an element doesen't exist then it must be $G\simeq\Bbb Z_{p}\times\Bbb Z_p$.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is perhaps to look out for an element of order $p^2$. If it exists, then the group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p^2$, otherwise it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p\times\mathbb{Z}/p$. The case $p=2$ is the easiest example for this.